# Input type "file" sometimes doesn't trigger the onchange event on a phone (and refreshes the page)

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

I have this input for uploading pictures, mostly intended for taking pictures with the phone's camera:

`<input type="file" accept="image/*,capture=camera" capture="environment" onchange="uploadImage(this);">`

It works fine on desktop, but **sometimes** on a phone it doesn't trigger the onchange event and the uploadImage() function doesn't get called when a picture is taken.

Like most answers on this topic suggested, I added the capture=camera part to the accept attribute, and added the capture="environment" attribute as well, and also I'm resetting the input.value at the end of the uploadImage function. But it didn't help.

Also, for some unknown reason, when the onchange doesn't happen, the page refreshes.

I've ran out of ideas of things to try, any suggestions?

Comment: `onchange` will only trigger when the focus from the input is lost. Losing the focus on mobile is harder than on desktop. You should not use the `onchange` trigger anyways. Use an `eventlistener` and combine it with `setTimeout` or `setIntervall` to check if a change happened while not losing focus.

Comment: @tacoshy not sure I understood the timeout part completely. should I use it to delay adding the event listener?

Comment: Good question and glad you asked it! No, you completely change the event from `change` to `keyup`. This will that you need to lose focus on the input but run the script as soon as a key was pressed and the pressure is lifted. However, you would start than to run the function every keyup. So you add a setInterval that delays the function. on every keyup you reset the time. Overall you will then trigger the function only after a keyup appeared and you have a certain time with no further keyup. This tests if the user is still typing or possibly is finished typing

Comment: @tacoshy why are we talking about typing when it's a type="file" input, for uploading or taking pictures with the camera?